# Modify the $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'], depending on the directory where index.php is located

Tags: php, .htaccess, request

I have a problem here:

I have the application that is running on virutalhost: example.com

The application processes all all reqests example.com/* and they fall into the index.php script where the magic happens further.

The components of magic environment variable $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'], everything works nicely, until I wanted to run the application in a subdirectory: example.com/abc/*

My question is:

How can I modify $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] with entries in .htaccess after entering the example.com/abc/whatever the index.php script 
in the $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI '] was the entry: /whatever and not /abc/whatever?

I made some research, and slowly come to the conclusion that it is only a modification of the $ _SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] in a index.php script is the one solution?

Has anyone an idea?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for this type of thing.

Instead use `define` and then use those definitions throughout your application. So for your subdirectory us this and then use `BASE_DIR` and `BASE_URL` throughout your application.

```
define("BASE_DIR", "/var/www/abc/");
define("BASE_URL", "/abc);
```

If you then need to move it again this is easily done, because you can just change those two variables and you don't need to worry about making sure $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is right.

```
define("BASE_DIR", "/var/www/sitename.com/httpdocs/subdir");
define("BASE_URL", "/subdir);
```

Note you use these definitions like so

```
echo "The base dir is " . BASE_DIR;
```

Comment: Ok but I need information about request generated by user:

if user type: /abc/action1 I want to get only action1 and all query params,
if user type: /abc/action2 I want to get only action2 and all query params

Informationa about Base url is not importatn for me :)

Comment: You need to reword your question, as that isn't what you have asked.

Comment: Sorry for problem , but I found solution:`RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L,E=PATH_INFO:/$1]` in .htaccess creates additional element in $_SERVER : REDIRECT_PATH_INFO, and then when I create request like: /abc/action1 I have  $_SERVER['REDIRECT_PATH_INFO'] = "/action1"

sorry for problem :)